# Can I check if a Unicode codepoint will be displayable under Android?

Tags: android, unicode, fonts, glyph, codepoint

My current project uses some symbols which are absent in many fonts. So far I've found some iOS renders as a box so I'm expecting sooner or later to find one that Android can't render too, though so far it's done better than iOS in this regard.

Is there a way to programatically check that a given Unicode codepoint will display correctly on the screen and not as an empty square box etc?

If I can detect a symbol can't be rendered I can implement a workaround for it rather than display an ugly box.

Comment: what symbols are being used and missing in the fonts?

Comment: So far I haven't found a missing one on Android but I found the new Armenian currency symbol ֏ was missing on iOS so I'm assuming that's not a one-off.

Comment: My co-developer has found that earlier versions of Android that I can't test does not have some of the Unicode national flag Emoijis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For general unicode characters you can use [PaintCompat.hasGlyph](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/PaintCompat.html#hasGlyph(android.graphics.Paint,%20java.lang.String)).

You should still use EmojiCompat that is mentioned in ianhanniballake's answer to be able to properly render emojis.

Answer (score 2):

With [Emoji Compat](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/emoji-compat.html), all current Unicode characters are supported back to API 19. It can be used with [Downloadable Fonts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts.html), ensuring that as additional Unicode characters become standardized, your app automatically supports them.

You can confirm if a specific character is supported by Emoji Compat with [hasEmojiGlyph()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/text/emoji/EmojiCompat.html#hasEmojiGlyph(java.lang.CharSequence)):

```
EmojiCompat.get().hasEmojiGlyph(charSequence);
```

> Note: you must have [initialized Emoji Compat](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/emoji-compat.html#downloadable-fonts-config) before calling this.

The [EmojiCompat DevByte video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BH33_MhxDOY) shows a minimal set of steps to get things working.

Comment: The characters I'm concerned with are not Emoji. Does this still apply?

Comment: I added a note on the `hasEmojiGlyph()` method, which should tell you exactly what will render as boxes (if it returns false) vs rich characters.

Comment: For general unicode characters you can use PaintCompat.hasGlyph.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/PaintCompat.html